# Regular Expression to find merge conflicts in file

Tags: javascript, regex, expression, regex-group

This is the file which contains merge conflicts,

```
<<<<<<< HEAD
$conf['some_unit_id'] = '4-qw-gg-ds-sometext';
=======
// Some Snippets Site Info
$conf['site_info'] = array(
  'customer_service_phone' => '+1 323223232
  'logo_path' => 'https://www.google.com/img/icons/src/logo.svg',
  'currency' => 'CAD',
    'https://www.youtube.com/user/somewebsite/ogog',
    'https://www.instagram.com/somewebsite/',
  ),
);
>>>>>>> ff6df3435231fdff78fwsd83e7dffa0732eft554

// Somes code
$done['rules'] = TRUE;
```

Am trying to find the best regular expression that detect merge conflicts in the file. Initially I tried with :

```
/(<* HEAD)/
```

Which will detect only `HEAD` with some preceding `<`
I have some other markers as well like :

```
1. ======
2. >>>>> ff6df3435231fdff78fwsd83e7dffa0732eft554
```

These two markers must detect along with `HEAD` marker as well. And if a developer fixes the merge conflicts only `<* HEAD` and rest of the ie., `===== and >>> ff6df3435231fdff78fwsd83e7dffa0732eft554` the regular expression should detect that as well.

Since this regular expression am using in pre-commit hook. If one pattern detected in file commit will break. I need exact regex to detect merge conflict markings.

Any solution would be appreciated.

Comment: Is [this](https://regex101.com/r/nA8QW5/1) what you want?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since they're all the same length, you can use a character group:

```
/^[<=>]{7}( .+)?$/mg
```

(make sure to use a [multiline](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp/multiline) regex)

Answer (score 3):

You can use:

```
^<{7} HEAD(?:(?!={7})[\s\S])*={7}(?:(?!>{7} \w+)[\s\S])*>{7} \w+
```

[Demo & explanation](https://regex101.com/r/nA8QW5/1)

Answer (score 1):

You might also match all the lines by checking the start of each line to prevent some of the unnecessary backtracking using `[\s\S]`.

First match the `<<<<<<< HEAD` part, then match all following lines that do not start with `=======` and then match it.

Then match all lines that do not start with `>>>>>>>`  followed by matching it and  chars [a-z0-9].

```
^<{7} HEAD(?:\r?\n(?!={7}\r?\n).*)*\r?\n={7}(?:\r?\n(?!>{7} ).*)*\r?\n>{7} [a-z0-9]+
```

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/W9Fx8B/1)

If you want to highlight the markers, you could use a capturing group:

```
^(<{7} HEAD)(?:\r?\n(?!={7}\r?\n).*)*\r?\n(={7})(?:\r?\n(?!>{7} ).*)*\r?\n(>{7} [a-z0-9]+)
```

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/Xwj3b6/1)

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly your desire, you want to find block code that need to resolve conflict. I hope my suggestion can help you.

```
/^<{7}\sHEAD[\s\S]+?>{7}\s\w+$/gm
```

Details:

- Mode: multiline
- ^<{7}\sHEAD: block code starts with <<<<<<< HEAD
- [\s\S]+?: get any character as few times as possible (line break accepted)
- > {7}\s\w+$: block code ends with >>>>>>> commit hash

[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/AOtnGq/2)

Comment: You will have problems if there're more than one merge conflict.

Comment: @Toto Thank you very much. I have corrected my regex.